# Oracle вариативный Update

Tags: sql, oracle, update

Возникла следующая проблема. В таблице test есть колонка is_hidden которая отвечает за показ информации пользователю, и колонка end_date которая содержит дату окончания некого действа. Мне необходимо реализовать следующую логику:
делать is_hidden = 1 для записей у которых end_date < sysdate -1 и делать is_hidden = 0 для записей у которых end_date > sysdate -1; Понимаю что можно легко сделать это двумя запросами, но возможно ли это сделать через 1 запрос?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/expressions004.htm

Comment: Да, это решило мою проблему! Спасибо!